# How to run a VB.NET .exe file on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos-5, mono-framework, vb.net

I would like to execute my `.exe` file written in VB.NET *(in VS 2008)* on CentOS 5.6.

I have installed mono. But I'm not that familiar with CentOS, so I don't know how to proceed.

---

I created a "Hello World" console app in VB.net and execute it using that code and everything work's well. But when i tried to execute a VB Windows form app, it throws me an error saying:

> The entry point method could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following command in Linux Terminal:

```
mono program.exe
```

Probably it will fail with an exception telling you what changes you need to make later.

See: [Porting Winforms Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/).

Every program that wants to target Mono must be remedied accordingly. For VB.NET apps, you might install mono full runtime (as on some Linux distro VB.NET is packaged separately and might not yet installed)..

Comment: Thank's a lot sir Lex Li. I created a "Hello World" console app in vb.net and execute it using that code and everything work's well. But when i tried to execute a vb windows form app, it throws me an error saying  'The entry point method could not be loaded'. Please help me regarding this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications Every program that wants to target Mono must be remedied accordingly. For VB.NET apps, you might install mono full runtime (as on some Linux distro VB.NET is packaged separately and might not yet installed).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed the following libraries:

- `mono-complete` package, e.g. by: `yum install mono-complete` (or `apt-get`).
- [.NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download), e.g. by `winetricks dotnet46`.

  <sup>Install winetricks by: `yum install winetricks` (or by `apt-get`).</sup>

Related: [Mono, failing to open executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/50735/78223).